# nginx - enabling cache for .css file with gzip compression

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have following nginx config. if I remove the cache config for css everything works and all css files load perfectly via reverse proxy. but when I put in cache config for .css that results in 404 for all my css resources:

```
location ~* \.css {
          add_header Cache-Control public;
          add_header Pragma public;
          add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
          expires 1M;
        } 

location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx chooses a single `location` to process a request. That `location` needs to be complete. See [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Your `location ~* \.css` block is missing the `proxy_pass` statement.

The `proxy_set_header` statements can be moved to the outer block and inherited by both `location` blocks.

For example:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}

location ~* \.css {
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    expires 1M;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```